# vue: V-input-file is not of type ‘HTMLFormElement’ error

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, gridsome

on Vue adding selected file to FormData ends with error in both v-input-file and input type=‘file’.

error massage:
Failed to construct ‘FormData’: parameter 1 is not of type ‘HTMLFormElement’.

```
<template>
 <Layout v-if="$store.state.user">

<v-form
      id='myform'
      name='myForm'
      class='myform'
      ref="form"
      lazy-validation
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      method="POST"
    >
      <!-- FILE UP-LOAD -->
      <template>
        <v-file-input
          :rules="rules_fileInput"
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/bmp"
          show-size
          counter
          label="PNG, JPEG, BMP"
          placeholder="Pick an image"
          prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
          @change="onFilePicked"
        />
      </template>

 <v-btn dark @click="submitForm">
      Save
 </v-btn>

 </v-form>
 </Layout>
 </template>

 <script>
   export default {
   data: () => ({
     imageUpload: null,
   }),
   methods: {
   onFilePicked(file) {
      this.imageUpload = file;
   },
   async submitForm() {
     
console.log('this.imageUpload:', this.imageUpload) // showing file 
//const headersImg = { headers:{ 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}};


const { data } = await axios.post(
  url,
  new FormData(
    `files.${this.imageUpload.name}`,
    this.imageUpload,
    this.imageUpload.name
  )
);
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glj1z.png)

the image above clearly some file data.

if i will try to append FormData like so:

```
async submitForm() {

  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append(
    `files.${this.imageUpload.name}`,
    this.imageUpload,
    this.imageUpload.name
  );

  //console.log('...formData:', ...formData);
  const urlLocal = 'http://localhost:1337/upload';
  const urlLive = 'http://www.events-pr-server.ml/upload';

  // client in netlefy, server in heroku with: Allow all Origin - for this demo

  try {
    const { data } = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: urlLive,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    });
```

results as: Files are empty

1. tatusCode: 400, error: “Bad Request”, message: “Bad Request”,…}.
2. data: {errors: [{id: “Upload.status.empty”, message: “Files are
   empty”}]}.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ7Dr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBX4W.png)

Comment: I dont see any function definition or a v-model, where `imageUpload` is being assigned a value

Comment: Also for `HTMLFormElement ` error it wont come, if you use the Vuetify components correctly

Comment: i have updated the post and added the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, i created a codepen to check the issue.

1. There is no `HTMLFormElement` error which i encountered, check below code pen
   https://codepen.io/kurtesy_/pen/MWJBwQX?editors=1111
2. Next to Post a formData using axios use the below protocol, you need to specify `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`

   ```
   axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "your_url",
      data: formData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
      });
   ```

Comment: thank you Nishant Patel for last response and the codepen, 
please have in mind the empty file error accrued on the axios post request -- while FormData shows: data before. please look at the 3 images above. 
i have tested your code example and i got [object Error] when posing to http://www.events-pr-server.ml/upload URL. (the server config: CROS allow all origins.) regards.

Comment: @user769371 where are you making the axios call, in which function? Are your sure, you are passing the formData correctly in that function?

Comment: Thank you Nishant Patel for last response, I have updated my code to show you from where i send the api - from submit click event... and i did try to use axois explicit syntax as well like you did - in my new code above. but i still got the same error. http 400, file empty. if you like to test it.. to post en image smaller then 20 mb to the above address and share the code with me? will be awesome.. from vanilla js its work like a charm... but tricky with Vue/Vuetify. Regards.

Comment: On more thing you can try is in your form-data, dont pass name and use do this `formData.append(
    `files.${this.imageUpload.name}`,
    this.imageUpload
  );`